# New tab or stay on page

Tags: workflow

Hi I'm working on a workflow product with a 'home' page for storing your files. I'm curious about whether there is a good reason for navigating to the file clicked vs. opening a new tab.

So far I haven't come across a solid reason for either. At a high level, opening a new tab feels more like working w/ the finder. The downside is that you might not have kept your home tab open or it could be hard to find. But the downside is also the same if you navigate to a new page on the same tab. I guess you'd want the user to know where they are whenever they are on the page.

Answer (score 1):

2 ways to decide

1. Do a usability testing, see if thats what the users expect
2. Use an established pattern, Google Drive does is based on the file type. If its an image, it opens it in a modal, if its a separate file altogether, like a spreadsheet, it'll open it in a new tab